# Why I can not use a struct that is field of a class in a fixed statement?

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

In this code, I want to create a pointer from MyStruct type but compiler shows me this error: "You cannot take the address of given expression".
Here is my code:

```
unsafe class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test test = new Test();

            //Error: You cannot take the address of given expression
            fixed (MyStruct* ms = &test.MyStruct) 
            {

            }

            fixed (int* a = &test.a) //Is OK
            {

            }

        }
    }

    unsafe class Test
    {
        public int a;
        public MyStruct MyStruct { get; set; } = new MyStruct();
    }

    unsafe struct MyStruct
    {
        public int A;
        public fixed int Ids[5];
        public int B;
    }
```

I don't understand why shows me this error. everything looks like ok?
Can anybody explain what happens in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a property in the context of the fixed-statement. If you turn the `MyStruct` property into a field, it will work.

```
unsafe class Test
{
    public int a;
    public MyStruct MyStruct = new MyStruct();
}
```

Comment: The reason why is that properties are basically just methods and even though auto-properties like here have a backing field the compiler compiler can't easily know what happens in a method.